# Included file always gets file from the root even when base href is set

Tags: javascript, html

I am including some javascript files but my website has tons of errors in the console because the file is retrieved from the wrong location.

I got a root folder in which my folder with the website is saved. They are both on the same domain.

When look at the errors I see the files are retrieved from my root folder, but the files are located in my website folder.

I set my base tag like so:

```
<base href="http://www.website.nl/projects/website1/">
```

My website is located inside website1. So when I add the following line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

You would except the file to be retrieved from: `http://www.website.nl/projects/website1/assets/js/jquery.js`

But my console says it's retrieved from: `http://www.website.nl/assets/js/jquery.js`

I have no .htaccess file or anything in my website folder. What is causing this?:

Comment: In your HTML document, is your script tag before the base tag?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob Yes all the js files are included after the base tag. I only set the viewport and content type above my base tag.

Comment: Is the resource actually being retrieved or are you getting a 403 error / JS functions-don't-exist-error?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try the following code:

```
<base href="/projects/website1/">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
```